# Replace product name by SKU in Woocommerce admin orders pages (shipping section)

Tags: php, woocommerce, admin, orders

I would like to replace the Product name by the SKU only in Woocommerce --> Orders --> Order Details in the backend admin of WordPress located in the Shipping section.

[image: sku instead of product name in shipping section]

I tried the following code but it didn't work. I am not skilled with PHP.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_shipping_get_name', 'filter_order_item_shipping_get_name', 10, 2 );
function filter_order_item_shipping_get_name( $item_name, $order_item ) {
    if ( is_admin() && $order_item->is_type('line_item') ) {
        $product = $order_item->get_product();

        if( $sku = $product->get_sku() ) {
            $item_name = $sku;
        }
    }
    return $item_name;
}
```

Is it possible to know the correct code to replace the Product name by the SKU only in Woocommerce --> Orders --> Order Details Shipping section in the backend admin of WordPress?

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: Good clear question with a reasonable attempt at a solution here Alexandre - I'm taking a swing at this right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter you want to use is `woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_value`. It takes 3 parameters, and the third one is a shipping object in the place you are hoping to hook in. You test that its tye is `'shipping'` to make sure you don't modify other areas. Next you have to get the parent order object, get the order items objects from that, and loop through them to build the output string.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_value', 'filter_order_item_display_meta_value', 10, 3 );
function filter_order_item_display_meta_value( $meta_value, $meta_object, $order_item ) {

    if ( is_admin() && $order_item->is_type('shipping') ) {

        $meta_values = [];
        $order = $order_item->get_order();
        $order_items = $order->get_items();

        foreach( $order_items as $order_item ){

            $quantity   = $order_item->get_quantity();
            $product    = $order_item->get_product();
            $sku        = $product->get_sku();
            $name       = $product->get_name();

            if( $sku ) {
                $meta_values[] = $sku . ' &times; ' . $quantity;
            } else {
                $meta_values[] = $name . ' &times; ' . $quantity;
            }
        }

        return implode( ', ', $meta_values );

    }

    return $meta_value;
}
```

Comment: That's so great. Thank you very much for your answer and for the explanation you gave to it. PHP is really powerful. I still don't understand how to read the code completely, but thanks to your help, I get a better idea of how it works. Thank you again.